# Lua move up (Y) 5 values from self?

Tags: lua

I just wanted to instantly be 5 values up above my head from where I am in the world, but this code is also pushing me (X and Z) to another Same Remembered Location. do you see anything wrong with the code?

```
function Behavior:Awake() 
local pos = self.gameObject.transform:GetLocalPosition()
    self.posy = pos.y
    
                if CS.Input.WasButtonJustPressed("sobe1") then
self.gameObject.transform:SetPosition( Vector3:New( self.posy + 5 ) )
```

Comment: My guess is that `SetPosition` replaces the position with the specified vector, but you construct it from a single value, omitting the original coordinates. `Vector3:New( pos.x, self.posy + 5, pos.z )` might work, but details about the used framework are needed in order to be sure. Also why is `posy` assigned on `self`? Is it supposed to be a local variable?

Comment: I´ll answer in a bit

Comment: the self is there because it is a script that is attached to the main character.
Your solution still did not work, This is my code in full:

`function Behavior:Awake() 
local pos = self.gameObject.transform:GetLocalPosition()
self.posx = pos.x
self.posy = pos.y
self.posz = pos.z

function Behavior:Update() 

if CS.Input.WasButtonJustPressed("sobe1") then
self.gameObject.transform:SetPosition( Vector3:New( self.posx, self.posy + 4.78, self.posz ) )


    end`
So, the character does warp up nicely just like I needed (moves up) but is taken back to a set position, it does not go u

Comment: does not go up, from the place it is standing at. here is a link to a screenshot of the 3 problems I am facing, the one I said here is the Second one! [link]http://aloan.neocities.org/1.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

your Behavior:Awake() function is being called, probably when you get out of bed, or whenever that event is triggered.

Those `self.posx .posy & .posz` values get stored in your character table, until you later access them from within your Behavior:Update() function.

You need to just call :getLocalPosition() *at the moment you need those values*.  So try getting rid of the :Awake() portion, and combine those coordinates into your update vector routine.

```
function Behavior:Update()
    if CS.Input.WasButtonJustPressed('sobe1') then
        local pos = self.gameObject.transform:GetLocalPosition()
        self.gameObject.transform:SetPosition( Vector3:New( pos.x, pos.y +4.78, pos.z ) )
    end  --  'sobe1'
end  --  Update()
```

Comment: will try that, (so happy for the answer!)